# I am trying to use onClick() to take the ID of the clicked button item and send it to another component to be used in the API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want to click on a button of one movie from a movies list and when I click the button it sends my movie component its ID to be used to fetch the API and display this particular movie page , I did half the goal by doing the onClick method but I do not know how to send it to the  other component and use it correctly with the API

This is my Movies List page  code with the button :

```
     NowMovies:[],
      isLoaded:false,
      target_id:null
    }
  }
    componentDidMount(){
     fetch('API')
   .then(data => data.json()).then(({results}) => { this.setState({ isLoaded: true, NowMovies: results })}
   )}

   chosen = id => {
     return() => {
        this.setState({target_id:id})
        console.log(this.state.target_id)

     }
   }
<Link>
          ***<Button onClick={this.chosen(Movie.id)}>Visit</Button></Link>***
```

It correctly gives me this result in console when I click on a Movie button

[image]

The Movie component which I need to send the id to :

```
import NowPlaying from '../Movies/NowPlaying'

export default class Movie extends Component{
constructor(){
  super();
  this.state={
    id:'',
    name:'',
    vote:'',
    date:'',
    image:'',
    time:'',
    genres:[],
    overview:'',
  }

}

   componentDidUpdate(){
     fetch(
     'API').then(data => data.json()).then(results=>{this.setState({name:results.title,vote:results.vote_average,overview:results.overview,date:results.release_date,time:results.runtime,genres:results.genres , image:results.poster_path})}) 
  }

render(){
return( 
  <div>
  <h1>{NowPlaying.target_id}</h1>
  <h2 className='name'>{this.state.name}</h2>
  <img  className='img'   style={{
}} src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w200${this.state.image}`}></img>
  <h4 className='details'>Realsed on: {this.state.date} rating:{this.state.vote}  runtime:{this.state.time} </h4>
  <p className='overview'>{this.state.overview}</p>
  <p className="submit">
  <label>Add your review</label><br/>
  <input></input><br/><br/>
  <button>Add Comment</button>
  </p>
  </div>
  )
}
}
```

Comment: I think you may want to look at how to use react routers url params here https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume You have mapped the movies list correctly and each of those can give You `id`. What I would suggest is using react router. You need to use `Link` from`react-router-dom` instead of a button and pass `id` inside the Link:

```
<Link to={'/movie/' + Movie.id}>Visit</Link>
```

You should create a route for this of course like:

```
<Route path="/movie/:id" component={MovieDetailsComponent}/>
```

Then You just have to get the `id` in `MovieDetailsComponent` and fetch the data about Movie. To get the `id` add in `ComponentDidMount()` function this:

```
const {id} = this.props.match.params
```

Also I encourage You to read more about react-router:
[react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start)

Comment: I did all the steps and it went well with the Link Router , but I still cant render the specific Movie with the ID  

```const {id} = this.props.match.params
```

I dont know how to use this to pass the ID for the API